# Подскажите что не так, почему ошибка AttributeError: 'MainWindow' object has no attribute 'sidGreen'

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, сигналы-слоты, qslider

Подскажите что не так, почему ошибка

> AttributeError: 'MainWindow' object has no attribute 'sidGreen'

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUI()

    def setupUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(550, 400, 500, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle('Выбор цвета')
        self.frmColor = QFrame(self)
        self.frmColor.setGeometry(310, 10, 180, 180)
        self.frmColor.setStyleSheet('background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0)')

        self.sidRed = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal, self)
        self.sidRed.setGeometry(10, 40, 280, 20)
        self.sidRed.setRange(0, 255)
        self.sidRed.valueChanged(self.resetColor())

        self.lblRed = QLabel('Красный: 0', self)
        self.lblRed.setGeometry(10, 10, 280, 20)

        self.sidGreen = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal, self)
        self.sidGreen.setGeometry(10, 100, 280, 20)
        self.sidGreen.setRange(0, 255)
        self.sidGreen.valueChanged(self.resetColor())

        self.lblGreen = QLabel('Зеленый: 0', self)
        self.lblGreen.setGeometry(10, 70, 280, 20)

        self.sidBlue = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal, self)
        self.sidBlue.setGeometry(10, 160, 280, 20)
        self.sidBlue.setRange(0, 255)
        self.sidBlue.valueChanged(self.resetColor())

        self.lblBlue = QLabel('Синий: 0', self)
        self.lblBlue.setGeometry(10, 130, 280, 20)

    def resetColor(self):
        red = self.sidRed.value()
        green = self.sidGreen.value()
        blue = self.sidBlue.value()
        self.lblRed.setText('Красный:' + str(red))
        self.lblGreen.setText('Зеленый:' + str(green))
        self.lblBlue.setText('Синий:' + str(blue))
        self.frmColor.setStyleSheet(f'background-color: rgb({red}, {green}, {blue})')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не правильно подключаете подключите сигнал к слоту.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUI()

    def setupUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(550, 400, 500, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle('Выбор цвета')
        self.frmColor = QFrame(self)
        self.frmColor.setGeometry(310, 10, 180, 180)
        self.frmColor.setStyleSheet('background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0)')

        self.sidRed = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal, self)
        self.sidRed.setGeometry(10, 40, 280, 20)
        self.sidRed.setRange(0, 255)
#        self.sidRed.valueChanged(self.resetColor())
        self.sidRed.valueChanged.connect(self.resetColor)        # +++

        self.lblRed = QLabel('Красный: 0', self)
        self.lblRed.setGeometry(10, 10, 280, 20)

        self.sidGreen = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal, self)
        self.sidGreen.setGeometry(10, 100, 280, 20)
        self.sidGreen.setRange(0, 255)
#        self.sidGreen.valueChanged(self.resetColor())
        self.sidGreen.valueChanged.connect(self.resetColor)      # +++  

        self.lblGreen = QLabel('Зеленый: 0', self)
        self.lblGreen.setGeometry(10, 70, 280, 20)

        self.sidBlue = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal, self)
        self.sidBlue.setGeometry(10, 160, 280, 20)
        self.sidBlue.setRange(0, 255)
#        self.sidBlue.valueChanged(self.resetColor())
        self.sidBlue.valueChanged.connect(self.resetColor)        # +++

        self.lblBlue = QLabel('Синий: 0', self)
        self.lblBlue.setGeometry(10, 130, 280, 20)

    def resetColor(self):
        red = self.sidRed.value()
        green = self.sidGreen.value()
        blue = self.sidBlue.value()
        self.lblRed.setText('Красный:' + str(red))
        self.lblGreen.setText('Зеленый:' + str(green))
        self.lblBlue.setText('Синий:' + str(blue))
        self.frmColor.setStyleSheet(f'background-color: rgb({red}, {green}, {blue})')
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.resize(700, 300)
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]